# Definition of principal term of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, definition

In "Introduction to functional differential equations" by Hale and Lunel (1993), I found the following definition of principal term.

Let $P(z,w)$ be a polynomial of the form

\begin{equation}
P(z,w)=\sum_{m=0}^{r}\sum_{n=0}^{s} a_{mn} z^m w^n \; .
\end{equation}

We call $a_{rs}z^rw^s$ the principal term of the polynomial if $a_{rs}\not=0$ and, if, for each
other term $a_{mn}z^mw^n$ with $a_{mn}\not=0$, we have either $ r > m$, $s > n$ or $r = m$,
$s>n$, or $r > m$, $s = n$.

I honestly do not understand this definition; if we write the polynomial as above with the assumption that $a_{rs}\not=0$, doesn't this means the principal term is exactly $a_{rs}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial $P(z,w)=z+w$ does not have a principal term; to write it in the form
\begin{equation}
P(z,w)=\sum_{m=0}^{r}\sum_{n=0}^{s} a_{mn} z^m w^n \;,
\end{equation}
we must have $r,s\geq1$. The only nonzero coefficients are $a_{10}=a_{01}=1$, so in particular $a_{rs}=0$. This means the polynomial has no principal term.

And indeed the definition is needlessly roundabout. Given a polynomial
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
P(z,w)=\sum_{m=0}^{r}\sum_{n=0}^{s} a_{mn} z^m w^n \; ,
\end{equation}
it is immediate that for every coefficient $a_{mn}$ of $P(z,w)$ we have $0\leq m\leq r$ and $0\leq n\leq s$. So for each coefficient other than $a_{rs}$ indeed the condition

> ...either $r>m$, $s>n$ or $r=m$, $s>n$, or $r>m$, $s=n$.

is satisfied. Hence the latter part of the definition is redundant.

What the definition seems to aim at, is the fact that the representation of the form $(1)$ is not unique. Indeed one might as well write
$$P(z,w)=\sum_{m=0}^{r+1}\sum_{n=0}^{s+1} a_{mn} z^m w^n \; ,$$
and define $a_{mn}=0$ if $m=r+1$ or $n=s+1$ or both. The definition fails, however, by incorrect double usage of the variables $r$ and $s$. This can be fixed as follows:

> Le
>   t $P(z,w)$ be a polynomial of the form
>   \begin{equation}
> P(z,w)=\sum_{m=0}^{r}\sum_{n=0}^{s} a_{mn} z^m w^n \; .
> \end{equation}
>   We call $a_{uv}z^uw^v$ the *principal term*  of the polynomial if $a_{uv}\neq0$, and for each other coefficient $a_{mn}$ with $a_{mn}\neq0$ we have $u\geq m$ and $v\geq n$.

Alternatively, and slightly less concretely, one might define it as follows:

> A polynomial $P(z,w)$ is said to have *principal term* $a_{rs}z^rw^s$ if it has a representation of the form
>   \begin{equation}
> P(z,w)=\sum_{m=0}^{r}\sum_{n=0}^{s} a_{mn} z^m w^n \;,
> \end{equation}
>   with $a_{rs}\neq0$.

Comment: Indeed your example does not satisfy the requirement that $a_{rs}\not=0$ which would be that $a_{11}\not=0$. I mean... the definition as stated above is redundant, isn't it?

Comment: @WilliamTomblin Ah, I overlooked this requirement! But it makes no difference; the polynomial still does not have a principal term, precisely because $a_{rs}=0$. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok, it is now clear that "not every polynomial has a principal term", but still in my opinion this definition is redundant... I would define the principal term as $a_{rs}$ if this term is not zero...

Comment: @WilliamTomblin I have expanded my answer; the definition is not correct. I have added two possible fixes to my answer; I also just noticed you have more or less sketched these definitions in your own answer already. I hope it helps anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have got the point now.

The fact is that the representation of a polynomial in the form

\begin{equation}
P(z,w)=\sum_{m=0}^{r}\sum_{n=0}^{s} a_{mn} z^m w^n \; .
\end{equation}

is not unique. For instance, we could write also

\begin{equation}
P(z,w)=\sum_{m=0}^{r+1}\sum_{n=0}^{s+1} a_{mn} z^m w^n \; .
\end{equation}

by setting to zero the new coefficients.

So, the correct definition is that the principal term of a polynomial is the term $a_{ij}z^iw^j$ if $a_{ij}\not=0$ and, for any other term $a_{mn}\not=0$, either $i>m$, $j>=n$ or $i=m$, $j>n$.

However, if we agreed on "the minimal representation" of a polynomial, I think we could just define the principal term as $a_{rs}z^rw^s$ if $a_{rs}\not=0$.